# Bring up keyboard when Appium doesn't want to?

Tags: python-3.x, xcode, automated-tests, appium

I have a test that opens a search bar, which is SUPPOSED to bring up the keyboard, works without issue when not being run in appium. But when run as a test a WebDriverException: “Keyboard not found” error commonly occurs.

`Connect Hardware Keyboard` is off on the simulator

I’ve the code into a try to capture the issue:

```
 try:
        search_bar.send_keys(search_term + "\n")
 except WebDriverException:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

but don’t know what to put in the `except` , anyone know how to press CMD+K on the keyboard as that actually brings up the keyboard? Or use send_keys with the absence of a keyboard…

Appium version: v1.11.1 (broken on v1.10 too)

Device: iPhone XR Simulator

Language: Python3

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show keyboard, you must tap on search bar as you normally do. You can do that by

```
search_bar.click()
search_bar.sendKey("any text")
```

> you must **not** add **unicodeKeyboard** and **resetKeyboard** in your DesiredCapabilities

Comment: Adding `click()` doesn't work and I don't have those in my capabilities

Comment: Use **Appium Desktop Inspector** to inspect the the exact automation id of the element. You must select the internal child element of text box.